# Why is this EventMachine Synchrony hiredis example returning a DefaultDefferable, rather than the value from the request?

Tags: ruby, redis, eventmachine

I have this bit of code:

```
require 'em-synchrony'
require 'em-synchrony/em-hiredis'

EventMachine.synchrony do
  redis = EventMachine::Hiredis::Client.connect
  puts redis.class.name

  redis.set('a', 'foo')
  puts redis.get('a') == 'foo' ## should be 'true'                                                                                                                                                                                             
  puts redis.get('c').nil?     ## should be 'true'                                                                                                                                                                                             

  EM.stop
end
```

which, if you store it on the filesystem at `/tmp/reddy.rb` does this:

```
$ ruby /tmp/reddy.rb 
EventMachine::Hiredis::Client
false
false
```

In both cases a [DefaultDeferrable](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/DefaultDeferrable.html) is returned. With a slight modification

```
puts EM::Synchrony.sync( redis.get('a') )
```

returns `'foo'` as expected. Now, what's really gets me confused, if you have a look at the [`em-synchrony/em-hiredis`](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony/blob/master/lib/em-synchrony/em-hiredis.rb) I'm including you'll see that EM::Hiredis::Client is pretty short:

```
class Client
  def self.connect(host = 'localhost', port = 6379)
    conn = new(host, port)
    EM::Synchrony.sync conn.connect
    conn
  end

  alias :old_method_missing :method_missing
  def method_missing(sym, *args)
    EM::Synchrony.sync old_method_missing(sym, *args)
  end
end
```

That is, EM::Synchrony.sync *should* already be invoked but doesn't appear to be. What am I overlooking? Why does not the bit of code listed behave as the em-synchrony documentation suggests that it should?

---

I am using

- em-synchrony-1.0.0
- eventmachine-0.12.10
- em-hiredis-0.1.0
- ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]

I am aware of [redis-rb](https://github.com/ezmobius/redis-rb) but prefer `em-hiredis` for it's pub/sub implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, em-synchrony does not monkey-patch em-hiredis correctly. That is, the Client definition you see there does not exist in the current version of em-synchrony, only in development HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question here: [Simple use of EM::Synchrony#sync causes 'root fiber' FiberError -- my fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750788/simple-use-of-emsynchronysync-causes-root-fiber-fibererror-my-fault)

The problem is to find the correct version of em-hiredis the patch was meant to be used with :/